# Connecting Xbox 360 to HP TouchSmart PC

Tags: xbox-360, monitor

I have an old HP TouchSmart PC and want to hook my Xbox 360 up to it. My PC does not have an HDMI or VGA, but has S-video and TV input. How can I use this as the display for my Xbox 360?

This is the back:

[image: Back of Desktop here:]

Comment: Wow, you have Coax on that thing.  That's old school.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question a bit. If I got anything wrong, go ahead and fix it.

Comment: if you have an rca breakout cable for your xbox then you'll only need svideo to rca (yellow)

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is a HDMI to S-Video Converter, such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GGFY6LW) one.
The conversion of the signal may lead to some minor lag though, as in you will experience input lag, because the picture needs a few milliseconds longer to the screen than usual.

*The product shown is only an example, I am not endorsing any brand. Use the search of your favorite online store to find one you like.*